# Strange error while writing parquet file to s3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

While trying to write a dataframe to S3 I am getting the below error with nullpointerexception. Sometimes the job goes through fine and sometime its failing.

I am using EMR 5.20 and spark 2.4.0

Spark session Creation

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
        .config("spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString", "true")
        .config("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", "false")
        .config("spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown", "true")
        .config("spark.sql.parquet.fs.optimized.committer.optimization-enabled","true")
        .getOrCreate()

spark.sql("myQuery").write.partitionBy("partitionColumn").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("inferSchema","false").parquet("s3a://...filePath")
```

Can anyone help resolve this mystery. Thanks in advance

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.S3Errors.isHttp200WithErrorCode(S3Errors.java:57)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:100)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:184)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.deleteObjects(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:127)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.deleteAll(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:364)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.doSingleThreadedBatchDelete(S3NativeFileSystem.java:1372)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.delete(S3NativeFileSystem.java:663)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.delete(EmrFileSystem.java:332)
  at org.apache.spark.internal.io.FileCommitProtocol.deleteWithJob(FileCommitProtocol.scala:124)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.deleteMatchingPartitions(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:122)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:557)
  ... 55 elided
```

Comment: There are multiple Spark writing policies. Looking at the error it is coming from the S3 side, instead of s3a://... try using the s3 policy instead so it would be s3:/...

Comment: could be a syntax error ... try this ```val spark = (SparkSession.builder()
        .config("spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString", "true")
        .config("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", "false")
        .config("spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown", "true")
        .config("spark.sql.parquet.fs.optimized.committer.optimization-enabled","true")
        .getOrCreate())```

Comment: Hi Tried both s3 and s3a. This is happening only when we are trying to overwrite. When there is no file in the outputpath, the job is running fine.

Comment: @DineshJ Did you end up finding a resolution to this?  I'm seeing the exact same behavior.

Comment: @DineshJ Any solution for this? It works perfectly when I'm writing it to csv but not with the parquet

Comment: would it help if you change the order of write and partitionBy? something like: `spark.sql("myQuery").partitionBy("partitionColumn").write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("inferSchema","false").parquet("s3a://...filePath")`

Answer (score 5):

You're using `SaveMode.Overwrite` and the error line `com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.deleteObjects(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:127)` indicates a problem during the deletion operation of the overwrite.

I would check and make sure the S3 permissions in the IAM policy for your EMR EC2 instance profile allow the `s3:DeleteObject` action for the file path in your call to write Parquet. It should look something like this:

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowWriteAccess",
  "Action": [
    "s3:DeleteObject",
    "s3:Get*",
    "s3:List*",
    "s3:PutObject"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": [
    "<arn_for_your_filepath>/*"
  ]
}
```

In between jobs do you use different file paths in your call to write Parquet? If so then that would explain the intermittent job failures

Comment: This solved my problem. I couldn't change permissions so i wrote to new s3 path.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in the AWS code. That is closed source -you have to take it up with them.

I do see a hint that this is an error in the code trying to parse error responses. Maybe something has failed, but the code on the client to pass that error response is buggy. Isn't that unusual-it's the failure handling that rarely gets enough test coverage